# date in string to be formated to mm/yyyy format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string variable strTemp with value "12/1/2014", I need to get the value as just "12/2014". How do I do that?

```
 strTemp = "12/1/2014"
```

after formatting, I want the value of strTemp to be 12/2014

```
 strTemp = "12/2014"
```

Comment: What is the format of source string?

Comment: Does your example show the 12th of January 2014? What have you tried?

Comment: Tried the DateTime.Parse(strTemp).ToString("mm/yyyy") and did not get the right answer. After seeing Josh answer below realised that I have to have the mm in caps (MM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime.Parse(strTemp).ToString("MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
 Convert.ToDateTime(strTemp).ToString("MM/yyyy")
```

Or

```
 CDate(strTemp).ToString("MM/yyyy")
```